# Was the "Cake Song" released in a soundtrack?

Tags: music, madoka-magica

I have 3 *Puella Magi Madoka Magica The Rebellion Story* soundtracks. they are,

- OP Single - Colorful
- ED Single - Kimi no Gin no Niwa
- Original Soundtrack

I believed this was all there was and while waiting for an appointment i searched though all 3 looking to see if i could find the *Cake Song* that the Puella Magi sing at the beginning of the movie (when the Nightmare is changed into a cake for Bebe to eat).

i thought i might find it as just before i listened to *wo ist die Kase?* from *Puella Magi Madoka Magica The Beginning Story & The Eternal Story Original Soundtrack*, Track 7. if i remember correctly this is the song/chant that's in the background when Sayaka and Madoka enter a labyrinth before Mami saves them, and it only goes for about 40-45 seconds (track file on my iPod/iPhone says 50 seconds however there's a block of silence at the end).

But after listening to all the songs in The Rebellion Story soundtracks i couldn't find the Cake Song. However i admit i didn't listen to the entirety of every song, rather the first couple of second then i skip about a couple of minutes to listen to another couple of seconds.

So i am wondering if the Cake Song was officially released on a soundtrack, if so which one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cake Song from *Puella Magi Madoka Magica the Movie Part III: Rebellion* has [not been officially released](https://wiki.puella-magi.net/Madoka_Magica_Soundtrack#Movie_3) as part of [any soundtrack](http://otakuworldsite.blogspot.com/2013/03/mahou-shoujo-madoka-magica-ost.html#.VfdAw5c-h8E) for the anime. Fortunately, there are many sites to download the mp3 for free.